# Mongoose - array of enum strings

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose, enums

I have a Schema that has a property with the type of array of strings that are predefined.

This is what I've tried to do:

```js
interests: {
    type: [String],
    enum: ['football', 'basketball', 'read'],
    required: true
}
```

The thing is that when I'm trying to enter a wrong value that isn't defined on the enum, to the array it wouldn't validate it with the enum list.

for example, this would pass which it shouldn't:

```js
{ "interests": ["football", "asdf"] }
```

because `"asdf"` isn't predefined in the enum list it shouldn't pass the validation but unfortunately, it passes the validation and saves it.

I've tried to check this thing with a string type of values instead of an array of strings and it works.

for example:

```js
interests: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['football', 'basketball', 'read'],
    required: true
}
```

for example, this is failing as expected:

```js
{ "interest": "asdf" }
```

In conclusion, I need a schema's property with a type of array of strings that would check it's elements based on predefined values

Is the most effective way to achieve this goal is by using the validate method or there is a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting from [here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/6102#issuecomment-364129706):

```
const SubStrSz = new mongoose.Schema({ value: { type: String, enum: ['qwerty', 'asdf'] } });
const MySchema = new mongoose.Schema({ array: [SubStrSz] });
```

Using that technique you will able to validate values inside of your array.

Comment: So I've tried to use your solution but unfortunately with no luck
this is what I've tried to do:
```javascript
const interestSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ value: { type: String, enum: ['football', 'basketball', 'read'] } });
var profileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ interests: { type: new mongoose.Schema({ array: [interestSchema] }) } })```
and this is my input json:
```javascript
{ "interests": { "array": [{ "value": "football" }, { "value": "asdf" }] } }
```
it still not validating `"asdf"`

Comment: Don’t you need to wrap the object of value with Schema as well?

Comment: This is it: `const interestSchema = new mongoose.Schema({  value: {  type: String, enum: ['football', 'basketball', 'read'] } });` isn't it?
please try to beautify this code on Text Editor because I can't write it in a better way on comments here

Answer (score 2):

You can try a custom validation?Like this

```html
const userSchema = new Schema({
  phone: {
    type: String,
    validate: {
      validator: function(v) {
        return /\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}/.test(v);
      },
      message: props => `${props.value} is not a valid phone number!`
    },
    required: [true, 'User phone number required']
  }
});
```

this is the docs:
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html

Answer (score 1):

with nestjs without to create subschema solution

```
export enum RolesEnum {
  User = 'user',
  Admin = 'admin'
}

...
export class User {
  ...
  @Prop({
    type: [String],
    enum: [RolesEnum.Admin, RolesEnum.User],
    default: []
  })
  roles: RolesEnum[]
  ...
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here distributers will be array of `distributerObj`, similarly you can define object of any type.

```
const distributerObj = new Schema({
    "dis_id": {
        "type": "String"
    },
    "status": {
        "type": "String"
    }
});
const productSchema = new Schema({
    "distributers": {
        "type": [distributerObj]
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use ref to make a relation to the defined enum schema

```
const actionsEnums = new Mongoose.Schema({value: { type: String, enum:["account-deletion","account-update"]}});

const Privilege = new Mongoose.Schema(
  {
    userLevel: { type: String, required: true },
    actions: [{type: String, refs: actionsEnums}],
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
const InterestSchema = new Schema({
 interests: {
   type: [{
     enum: ['which', 'ever', 'values', 'allowed'],
   ]}
  }
})
```

hope this helps